# Why Flutter on iOS can't play an audio file from an URL but only from an IP address?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Does anyone know why Flutter only accepts an IP Address like this `http://37.59.41.148:17212/` and not a normal Url like this `http://stm16.abcaudio.tv:25584/player.mp3` (I test it in on an iPhone)?
I used this package: [`url_audio_stream`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_audio_stream).
I have also used other packages but it was the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. For those of you who have the same problem as me. To play URLs on an IOS device you have to put this in your Info.plist.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```